# HTTP Signature Authentication

Tags: cybersource

I am not able to make an authenticated call against Cybersource api and apitest environments, even though my signature routine is able to generate the correct signature from their test page.

I tried different headers combination, upper and lower case, and date vs v-c-date field names.

I constructed the signature from the following headers components.

```
'VB, Signature Construction

Dim pHost As String = "host: apitest.cybersource.com"
Dim pMerc As String = "v-c-merchant-id: testmid"
Dim pDate As String = "v-c-date: " & Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString("r")
Dim pReq As String = "(request-target): get /reporting/v3/report-downloads?organizationId=testmid&reportDate=2018-10-27&reportName=Demo_Report"
Dim pHeader As String = pHost & Chr(10) & pDate & Chr(10) & pReq & Chr(10) & pMerc
Dim kID As String = "{secret key}"
Dim mSig As String = GenerateSignatureFromParams(pHeader, kID)
Dim pSig As String = "signature: keyid=""{key id}"", algorithm=""HmacSHA256"", headers=""host v-c-date (request-target) v-c-merchant-id"", signature=""" & mSig & """"
```

When added the host, v-c-merchant-id, v-c-date, and signature to the request header for a GET, I received a response of (401) Unauthorized.

Answer (score -1):

The header names are:
$headerString = "host date (request-target) v-c-merchant-id"

appears your name "v-c-date" should be "date"